# Botframework: How much of the conversation is stored in DirectLineClient.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync method?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

In Microsoft Botframework, DirectLineClient.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync(conversationId) method is used to retrieve existing conversation. But how much of the conversation is stored in  method?
**Does it depends on number of Activites or number of days and if so, then how many?**

*PS: I know we can pass watermark to retrieve activities since that watermark, but this is not what I want to know.*

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 0):

[From GitHub:](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4237#issuecomment-374247785)

> The DirectLine most recent history cache is at most 24 hours. (for privacy reasons) The reason this cache exists at all is that some DirectLine clients are unreliable endpoints (such as web pages) and need to be able to retrieve the message after page refresh.

Comment: It looks like it retains more than that. As per my testing till now, it is displaying 14 days old conversation data. It was not able to display 33 days old conversation. I am still not able to get the exact number of days!

Comment: Conversation ID for a given user should be available for > 24 hours (ie the conversation should be reusable for up to twoish weeks).
Message content itself should be limited to 24 hours.
 

Are you saying that the content is available > 24 hours?